# How to get last inserted id into jdbc in jsp

Tags: jsp, jdbc, insert

How can I get ID from just inserted row in jsp?

```
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Recipients(CustomerID,Name, Street, City, ZipCode, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress,"
            + " ContactPersonName, ContactPersonSurname, ContactPersonPhoneNumber,ContactPersonEmailAddress) "
            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

And I need use id from Recipients to insert it into Parcels

```
PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Parcels(TransportTypeID,CustomerID,RecipientID,ParcelAmount, DimLength, DimHeight, DimWidth, ParcelWeigth, Content,"
            + " AdditionalDescription, IsCustomParcel, ReceiptFee, InsuranceAmount, OwnPick, DispatchDate) "
            + "values((?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");

    ps2.setString(1,transportTypeID);
    ps2.setString(2,customerID);
    ps2.setInt(3,recipientID); ...
```

I was trying to use ResultSet:

```
int recipientID=0;
    ResultSet rs2=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Recipients");
    if(rs2.last())
           {
            recipientID = rs2.getInt("RecipientID");
           }
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Which rdbms are you using? For example, if you are using Oracle, you can use a CallableStatement rather than a PreparedStatement and then use the "RETURNING id INTO  ?" to get the return value.

Comment: Im using Oracle's Mysql Workbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String query = "BEGIN " +
               "  INSERT INTO Recipients( CustomerID, Name, Street, City, ZipCode, PhoneNumber" + 
               "                         ,EmailAddress, ContactPersonName, ContactPersonSurname" +
               "                         ,ContactPersonPhoneNumber, ContactPersonEmailAddress) " +
               "    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING id into ?; " +
               "END;";

CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(query);

cs.setString(1,transportTypeID);
cs.setString(2,customerID);
cs.setInt(3,recipientID);
...
cs.registerOutParameter(12, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

cs.execute();

int id = cs.getInt(12);
```

Then use the resultant id for your next insert.  Or you could also put it all into a proc.

Comment: I'm using mysql-connector-java. I can't use "OracleTypes"

Comment: @Paul I removed the Oracle specific type. It was not necessary.

Comment: now I'm getting error: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 12 is not an OUT parameter

Comment: @Paul Probably a counting issue? Count the number of question marks and see that things line up. But it may be easier to start with a simple test, a two column table, insert one return the other. Make sure it works in the simple case. Also, take a look at this and other samples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942203/callablestatement-registeroutparameter-multiple-row-result

Comment: Same question actually answered here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552260/plsql-jdbc-how-to-get-last-row-id

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution:
`ResultSet rs2=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Recipients ORDER BY RecipientID DESC Limit 1;");
        while(rs2.next())
        {
            recipientID = rs2.getInt(1);
        }`