# Access an array returned from an oracle procedure

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

My oracle procedure returns an array of string and I call the procedure from my java method. 
When I execute the query I get the following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation
```

Note:

I have used OracleTypes.ARRAY here but I also tried using Types.ARRAY and it still gave me the same error.

**My Java method:**

```
public void searchRecords() throws FinderException{
        Session session = getCurrentSession();
        Connection con = session.connection();
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        String procCall = "call pkg_inquiry.test2(?,?)";

        try{            
            stmt = con.prepareCall(procCall);
            stmt.setInt(1, 1);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY);
            //stmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY);
            stmt.execute(); //-----------This statement causes exception

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

}
```

**MY Procedure:**

```
   PROCEDURE test2(
      p_in      in INTEGER,
      p_out    OUT header_row_vt
      )  
      is 
          BEGIN 
          p_out := header_row_vt('NAME', 'AGE', 'CITY', 'STREET'); 

     END test2;
```

If you want to know I am using Oracle 11.2 and jdbc 11.2

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem. My first guess was that the driver's sub-version (11.2.0.3) did not match the database's version (11.2.0.2), but this was not the case.

I got it to work eventually by declaring a return type in the database and calling `stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "TYPE_NAME");` instead.

An example for this is provided here:
[CallableStatement + registerOutParameter + multiple row result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942203/callablestatement-registeroutparameter-multiple-row-result)

Comment: I don't think that it makes a difference whether you use OracleTypes.ARRAY or Types.Array, since both of them refer to the int value of 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I cant test your code right now but seems like the issue is following:

If you are using `OracleTypes` then you should use `OracleCallableStatement`

```
OracleCallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(procCall);
```

Also if you want to use `CallableStatement` try `java.sql.Types.ARRAY`

Cheers !!

Comment: Please give a try to `OracleCallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(procCall);`, will test it out later in the day.

Comment: I did OracleCallableStatement stmt = (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall(procCall); and I got class cast exception.

Comment: Can you please provide complete package definition for pkg_inquiry